How do I install a different version of Spark using jupyter/pyspark-notebook?
I would like to install the Spark 4.0 preview using the jupyter/pyspark-notebook as the base.
The docker stacks documentation suggests that I can override the Spark version. I've tried this in my Docker file but it's still installing Spark 3.5.
FROM quay.io/jupyter/pyspark-notebook
ARG spark_version=4.0.0-preview1
ARG spark_download_url="https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/"

Looking for some guidance on how to achieve what I want to do.

This question is similar to: How do I set the driver's python version in spark?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

My question is specific to building a docker image from Jupyter/pyspark-notebook and overriding the version of Spark. Your response appears to be related configuring spark
